# Can't log in to answers.ros.org using Google Authentification

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have my ros answers account linked to my google account. When I try to log in with this google account, it takes me to the account creation screen, as if my account doesn't exist, and if I try to add it again as a new login method, I get an internal server error. The only way to log in (which doesn't always work) is to use the "Recover your account via email" button.

Ideas? I've heard google authentication can be a bit twitchy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12316/can%27t-log-in-to-answers.ros.org-using-google-authentification/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2011-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the google authentication all the time and haven't seen any hiccups.  If you can identify a time this is a problem we can try to take a look at the logs.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-12-13**:
Just made it happen (8:21AM PST).